# From geometric sequence to function

Tags: calculus

I have this question:

Find the functions which equal the sums:
$$
x + x^3 + x^5 + ..
$$

Now, I can see in my result list, that its supposed to give

$$
\frac{x}{(1-x^2)}
$$

I can see why the numerator should be x, but I fail to see why the denominator should be 
$$
(1-x^2)
$$
Can someone please explain this to me?

- David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the geometric series we have
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+...$$
When we fill in $x^2$ instead of x we get
$$\frac{1}{1-x^2}=1+x^2+x^4+x^6$$
Multiplying with x
$$\frac{x}{1-x^2}=x+x^3+x^5+x^7+...$$
On het other hand is a function uniquely determined by his Taylor expension so that the only possible answer to this question is $\frac{x}{1-x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite it as $x\left(1+(x^2)^1+(x^2)^2+\dots+(x^2)^k+\dots\right)$, and use what you know about the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha^k$ for $|\alpha| < 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let your series be $s(x)$ with $s(x)=xp(x)$

Then note that $x^2p(x)=p(x)-1$ which reduces to $p(x)=\cfrac 1{1-x^2}$

Answer (score 0):

This is a infinite geometric series which has first term $a=x$ and common ratio $r=\dfrac {x^3}{x}\implies r=x^2 $

sum of infinite geometric series is $s_{\infty}=\dfrac {a}{1-r} when |r|<1 $
$$s_{\infty}=\dfrac {x}{1-x^2}$$